# SSIS - How to trigger a restore of a transaction log backup file?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

In SQL Server 2005 Integration Services, how can I automatically trigger a restoration of a transaction log backup file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a quick search and found this piece of T-SQL somewhere, just create a new 'Execute SQL' task in your package and give it a shot...

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Restore database from a backup file
-- NOTE: If the database gets locked in Single user mode, execute 
--       the below command on it and it will restore the Multiuser mode:
--       ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename SET MULTI_USER
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use master
go

declare @backupFileName varchar(100), @restoreDirectory varchar(100),
 @databaseDataFilename varchar(100), @databaseLogFilename varchar(100),
 @databaseDataFile varchar(100), @databaseLogFile varchar(100),
 @databaseName varchar(100), @execSql nvarchar(1000)

-- Set the name of the database to restore
set @databaseName = 'myDatabase'
-- Set the path to the directory containing the database backup file.
--IMPORTENT:: Make sure theer is a \ character at the end of your directory path below, else 
-- the script will error out
set @restoreDirectory = 'aboslute_path_to_restore_directory' -- such as 'c:\temp\'

-- Create the backup file name based on the restore directory, the database name and today's date
set @backupFileName = @restoreDirectory + @databaseName + '-' + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 110), '-', '.') + '.bak'

-- Get the data file and its path
select @databaseDataFile = rtrim([Name]),
 @databaseDataFilename = rtrim([Filename])
from master.dbo.sysaltfiles as files
 inner join
 master.dbo.sysfilegroups as groups
 on
 files.groupID = groups.groupID
where DBID = (
  select dbid
  from master.dbo.sysdatabases
  where [Name] = @databaseName
 )

-- Get the log file and its path
select @databaseLogFile = rtrim([Name]),
 @databaseLogFilename = rtrim([Filename])
from master.dbo.sysaltfiles as files
where DBID = (
  select dbid
  from master.dbo.sysdatabases
  where [Name] = @databaseName
 )
 and
 groupID = 0

print 'Killing active connections to the "' + @databaseName + '" database'

-- Create the sql to kill the active database connections
set @execSql = ''
select @execSql = @execSql + 'kill ' + convert(char(10), spid) + ' '
from master.dbo.sysprocesses
where db_name(dbid) = @databaseName
 and
 DBID <> 0
 and
 spid <> @@spid
exec (@execSql)

print 'Restoring "' + @databaseName + '" database from "' + @backupFileName + '" with '
print '  data file "' + @databaseDataFile + '" located at "' + @databaseDataFilename + '"'
print '  log file "' + @databaseLogFile + '" located at "' + @databaseLogFilename + '"'

set @execSql = '
restore database [' + @databaseName + ']
from disk = ''' + @backupFileName + '''
with
  file = 1,
  move ''' + @databaseDataFile + ''' to ' + '''' + @databaseDataFilename + ''',
  move ''' + @databaseLogFile + ''' to ' + '''' + @databaseLogFilename + ''',
  norewind,
  nounload,
  replace'

exec sp_executesql @execSql

---------------End of Restore script---------------------------------------
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping to find a native SSIS component which just do the job, but it works, who's complaining?